# Lipschitz contraction

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to solve this problem but without sucess. Does this even count as contraction mapping?

> Let $h:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a contraction with Lipschitz constant $\lambda \in ]0,1[$. Suppose $h(0)=0$, and define $F(x,y,z)=(\frac{h(x)-y}{2},\frac{x}{2})$. Let $D=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 :x^2+y^2\le1\}$ Show that $F(D)\subseteq D^*$.

Comment: To be honest I dont even know how to start. I know what I have to do but don't know how to do it.

Comment: Prove first that $\vert h(x)\vert\leq \vert x\vert$. Then you can directly verify that $F(D)\subset D$ (i.e if $(x,y)\in D$ then $F(x,y)\in D$). It's helpful to note that for $(x,y)\in D$ holds $\vert x\vert, \vert y\vert\leq 1$.

Comment: I reformatted your LaTeX to make the question more readable; hope that's OK.  But is $F$ supposed to be a function of two variables, or three?  You gave it three variables, but didn't “use” $z$, then talk about applying it to a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Also, what is $D^*$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noting $h(x)$ is a a contraction with Lipschitz constant $\lambda $ in $]0,1[$, one has 
$$ |h(x)|\le \lambda|x|\le |x|. $$
Thus, for $(x,y)\in D$, namely $x^2+y^2\le1$, one has
$$ (\frac{h(x)-y}{2})^2+(\frac{x}{2})^2=\frac{1}{4}[x^2+y^2-2h(x)y+h^2(x)]\le\frac{1}{4}[1-2h(x)y+h^2(x)]\le\frac{1}{4}[1+y^2+2h^2(x)]\le\frac{1}{4}[2+2h^2(x)]\le 1$$
namely $F(x,y)\in D$.

Comment: How do you get those last inequalitys??